# css transition dependent on password field presence

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

It seems to be the case that if I have a password input inside a form element, and if I load an *external* stylesheet that defines a simple css transition, then that transition applies as the page loads. That's great.

But if I remove the password field or if I remove the form, or if I embed the styles into the document, the transitions no longer apply.

Why does this animation seem to depend on the presence of the password field? Why does it need to be inside a form? And why does it matter whether I load the stylesheet from an external file with a `link` tag or just embed it within a `style` tag?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#">HELLO</a>
    <form>
      <input type="password">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

stlyle.css:

```
body { font-size: 100px; }
a { transition: all 0.3s ease-out; }
```

Comment: I don't think it should matter.. where is your animation happening in the code?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to transition?  With this code you just have an `<a>` tag.  If you have a `:hover` state, then the transition works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/RsWBm/

Comment: Check out the difference between these two pages: http://lithostech.com/css-transition/with-password/ and http://lithostech.com/css-transition/without-password/

I'm really not trying to accomplish anything other than to explain this behavior.

Comment: Just a bit more info. I am seeing this issue in chrome 35.0.1916.114 but not firefox. But I'm not sure if this is a chrome-specific issue.

Comment: the difference might come from the fact that CSS from external file is loaded after HTML. Here nput password might need some extra ressource that Chrome loads only when needed. The result is a delay to apply the linked style sheet over the HTML. here a codepen where you can experiment something similar in chrome, the only first time you load it, then CSS is cached and applied right away. http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/full/rmhAp/